# Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh

Нужно поправить сайт, а я даже авторизоваться на сервере не смог :)

Ввожу привычную команду в терминал:

```
ssh root@111.222.333.444 -p 12045
```

И в ответ получаю:

> Permission denied (publickey).

Что в таком случае необходимо сделать? Сколько раз до этого не авторизовывался на других серверах, всегда все было нормально.

Comment: у вас есть private ключ для этого сайта?

Comment: если вы ожидали аутентификацию логин-пароль, то она, скорее всего, запрещена на сервере, а доступна только по публичному ключу (во всяком случае - для пользователя root).

Comment: @Etki то есть я никак не смогу авторизоваться без ключа, который мне может дать только системный администратор того сервера?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman у меня есть только ip, port, login, password.

Comment: а login root? это вы на какой-то хостинг заходите?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman коннект к капельке DO. Попросили пофиксить сайт.

Comment: @Colibri при создании дроплета публичный ключ указывали?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman это не мое. Меня просто человек попросил помочь ему, а я даже не смог авторизоваться. У него спрашивать об этом было бесполезно, так как ему этот дроплет ставил кто-то еще.

Comment: Это вероятно (я просто не уверен, что вывод свидетельствует именно об этом). В любом случае я бы попробовал достучаться до админа.

Comment: Add a new SSH key to your GitHub account

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/resources/lost-ssh-key/